# How to display markers for different devices?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am developing an application that displays a map and markers successfully in android 2.3 device but in android 4.3 device it does not display any markers on map. I'm not getting any error.

Code:

```
 GoogleMap _googleMap;
 LatLng myPosition;
 LocationManager locationManger;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_map_when_login);

    _googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.mapId)).getMap(); 

    LocationManager service = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    boolean enableGPS = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean enableWiFi= service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if(!enableGPS || !enableWiFi){
        Toast.makeText(ShowMapWhenLoginActivity.this, "GPS signal not found", 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    locationManger = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


    service.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);


    if(_googleMap==null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Google Map Not Available", 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //locationManger.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,   
   this);
    _googleMap.clear();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) 
            getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arrayList");


    if(location!=null){
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double langitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latlang = new LatLng(latitude, langitude);

        myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, langitude);

    }
         if(arl.size()!=0){


            for(int j = 0;j<arl.size();j++){


         /* Log.e("SIZE", ""+arl.size());
          Log.e(" NEW LAT",arl.get(j).get("lat").toString());
          Log.e(" NEW LONG",arl.get(j).get("lng").toString());
          Log.e(" NEW ADDRESS",arl.get(j).get("address").toString());
          Log.e(" NEW CTIME",arl.get(j).get("ctime").toString());
          */

          String lat =arl.get(j).get("lat").toString();
          String lng =arl.get(j).get("lng").toString();
          if ( !lat.trim().equals("") && !lng.trim().equals("") ) {
          double Hlat = Double.parseDouble(lat.trim());
          double Hlong= Double.parseDouble(lng.trim());

          LatLng dabaseLocations =new LatLng(Hlat, Hlong);

          Marker HYD = _googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()

          .position(dabaseLocations)
          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
          .flat(true));

          // Show current location with database locations


          _googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition,5)); 
           Marker m=_googleMap.addMarker(new 
   MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("start"));
          // HYD.setPosition(new LatLng(5,5));

             }
           }

     }
         else{

             // Show only Current Location

        _googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition,5)); 
        _googleMap.addMarker(new    
 MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("start"));

    }

}


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Comment: post the code where you add markers please

Comment: May be 4.3 version device uses updated Map. Check both Map versions in device.

Comment: i added my code please see

Comment: And you are positive that GPS is enabled on the device? If onLocationChanged is never called, then no markers will get added.

Comment: ya the GPS is enabled in device

Comment: I would make a Log output in onLocationChanged, just to make sure that it is actually getting called.